# How to handle datatype double-precision float [DT_R8] in ssis data flow task

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I am having SSIS data flow task where I need to transfer data from one sql database to another sql database.
My source Database column datatype in SQL is `float` and in ssis its `double-precision float [DT_R8]`.
Destination column datatype is `Varchar(50)` . When i execute the data flow , data transferred to destination table differs from source data eg:

```
    +------------+---------------------------------+
    | SourceValue| DestinationValue After execution|
    +------------+---------------------------------+
    | 0.579      | 0.578999999999999965            |
    | 0.637      | 0.63700000000000001             |
    | 0.503      | 0.503                           |
    +------------+---------------------------------+
```

So for some values its same but different for other.
I have tried 3 approaches to solve this issue :-

1. Tried to cast in query as `cast(col as varchar)`
2. Tried to cast as float `cast(col as float)`
3. Tried to change datatype in SSIS destination column same as of source ie. `double-precision float [DT_R8]` . though i am getting warning that datatype needs to change while executing.

But none of above steps solved my problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found solution that in source flow I have changed datatype from `double-precision float [DT_R8]` to `DT_DECIMAL` . Its working fine now , values are transferred to destination table as it is .

eg:

```
+------------+---------------------------------+
    | SourceValue| DestinationValue After execution|
    +------------+---------------------------------+
    | 0.579      | 0.579                           |
    | 0.637      | 0.637                           |
    | 0.503      | 0.503                           |
    +------------+---------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way float works. I assume that you are using some tool to view the source values: most tools will trim float values (round them for display), so I would bet that 0.579 is actually 0.5789999 etc etc. If you don't know it already, float values are not precise anyway. Have a look at the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point), especially section 7: Accuracy Problems.

Comment: Ok.. But how do i get exactly what was entered source database in destination database column ??